# Creating a dynamic check box based on selected dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to create a dynamic checkbox based on selected value text from drop-down list.

For example the drop-down list will have:

(`test1`, `test2`, `test3`)

So if I select `test2` it will create a check box called `test2` and so dynamically check box will get created.

Comment: Why do you need to create a checkbox when you already have the value from the select menu? I'm confused here.

Comment: Hi, this created check box will have side by 1 more linked button with few other details. and In the selected drop down list will more 5k records so whichever record wanted only will create a checkbox and go further functionalities

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div id="selectContainer">
    Step 1: 
    <select id="testSelect" name="test">
        <option></option>
        <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="checkboxContainer"></div>​
```

JS

```
function callback(event) {
    var input     = document.createElement('input'),
        container = document.getElementById('checkboxContainer');

    if (!this.value &&  !event.srcElement.value) {
        return false;
    }

    input.type = 'checkbox';
    input.name = this.value || event.srcElement.value;

    container.innerHTML = '';
    container.appendChild(input);
}

try {
    // W3C
    document.getElementById('testSelect').addEventListener('change', callback);
} catch (e) {
    // Microsoft
    document.getElementById('testSelect').attachEvent('onchange', callback);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VGAMR/